# Cannot mock a method in mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I tried mocking this function but the `record` variable is always null

Here is the code in the service:

```
val record: LockDatabaseRecord = lockDatabaseRecordService.getTransLockDbRecord(dbRecordId) {
    it.lockDatabaseRecordKeys.size
}
```

And this is how I mocked it

```
 @Test
    fun failedEngageSessionItem() {
        val dbVersion = "0x0000001"
        val sessionId = UUID.randomUUID()
        val dbRecordId = UUID.randomUUID()
        val requestDetails = "request details"
        val recordDbVersion = "1x"

        val lockId = UUID.randomUUID()
        val lock = mock(Lock::class.java)

        val lockDatabaseRecord = mock(LockDatabaseRecord::class.java)
        val lockDatabaseRecordKey = mock(LockDatabaseRecordKey::class.java)
        val key = mock(Key::class.java)

        `when`(lockService.getTransLock(eq(lockId), any())).thenReturn(lock)
                `when`(lockDatabaseRecordService.getTransLockDbRecord(eq(dbRecordId), any())).thenReturn(lockDatabaseRecord)
```

Comment: Is `lockDatabaseRecordService` also a mock? It has to be, since you defined its behaviour in the `when` statement

Comment: Yes! it is a mock

Comment: In your test, you appear to be calling the overloaded getTransLockDbRecord with 2 arguments, but the code calls the 1 arg version.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you call it, it seems like `getTransLockDbRecord` accepts two arguments (an id and a lambda that returns the size of keys). Make sure you mock it exactly like it is supposed to be called, icluding the lambda parameter.

In the bitecode, these two calls would be calls to two different methods (with overloaded signatures), you need to make sure the correct one is called.

Mockito might also have issues comparing lambdas. If mocking doesn't work I would suggest you first try it with `Mockito.any()` just to make sure it manages to mock it.

```
`when`(lockDatabaseRecordService.getTransLockDbRecord(eq(dbRecordId), any()))
     .thenReturn(lockDatabaseRecord)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code above, but for some reason, it returns `eq(dbRecordId) must not be null`. Do you have any idea what is the reason? :think:

Comment: @mengmeng are you sure `dbRecordId` is not null in your case? Could you double check it?

Comment: Yes. dbRecordId is just `val dbRecordId = UUID.randomUUID()` hmmm

Comment: @mengmeng can you post a full code snippet?

Comment: @mengmeng can you also post the exact error that you get? What line of code does it produce?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late revert. I just got back from work. But I just got a nullexception with the error `eq(dbRecordId) must not be null`